# When to properly release an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to better understand when to properly release an object in a fairly memory intensive program.  My current doubt arises from the following bit of code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)localScrollView
{
    InteractionPointModel *model = [[InteractionPointModel alloc] init];

    for (int x=0; x<totalInteractionPoints; x++) {

        model = [interactionPointData objectAtIndex:x];
        CGPoint oldCenter = model->worldLocation;
        CGPoint newCenter;
        newCenter.x = oldCenter.x * [localScrollView zoomScale];
        newCenter.y = oldCenter.y * [localScrollView zoomScale];
        [[interactionPoints objectAtIndex:x] setCenter:newCenter];
    }
    [model release];
}
```

I would have thought that the program was done with model by now, but it crashes upon release.  If I don't release it, the program runs, but obviously with a memory leak.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm starting to feel that the problem arises with interactionPointData, since this method does not own it.  Since I am pointing to it with model, will releasing model cause havoc upstream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are leaking when you first enter on the loop.

```
InteractionPointModel *model = [[InteractionPointModel alloc] init];
```

The line above is allocating an object that won't be used.

```
model = [interactionPointData objectAtIndex:x];
```

The line above makes `model` point to a different object, and so, the previous value is not pointed anymore.

```
[model release];
```

You get the crash when releasing because you are releasing a value that you don't own. When you get at release, if you enter on the loop, at least once, `model` is pointing to the last object of the array `interactionPointData`.

To fix your code, you need only to remove the wrong memory management.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)localScrollView {
    InteractionPointModel *model = nil;
    for (int x=0; x<totalInteractionPoints; x++) {
        model = [interactionPointData objectAtIndex:x];
        CGPoint oldCenter = model->worldLocation;
        CGPoint newCenter;
        newCenter.x = oldCenter.x * [localScrollView zoomScale];
        newCenter.y = oldCenter.y * [localScrollView zoomScale];
        [[interactionPoints objectAtIndex:x] setCenter:newCenter];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be replacing a newly-allocated `InteractionPointModel` object with an existing one in your `interactionPointData` array. At the end of the method, after the loop, you're attempting to release <del>what I suspect is an autoreleased object (coming from the array)</del> as you say in your comment, an object from the array that you don't own, which causes the crash.

If you don't release it, the leak is caused by the newly-allocated object that you initialized at the beginning, which is no longer accessible because you've changed `model` to point to objects in the array.

Comment: Yes, this is what I suspect, upon further inspection.  Thank you, this definitely gives me an idea of where to seek out the problem!